# Which Hash functions can be used in count-min sketch?

Tags: data-structures, hash, language-agnostic, count-min-sketch

The number of elements in my set are over a billion 2<sup>30</sup>. I intent to count the occurrence of each element in the set. For this purpose, I want to use count-min sketch. Please suggest how the hash functions should be chosen. The false positive rate of at most 5% is tolerable for my application.

Comment: What is the value range? Do you have any information about the distribution of the values?

Comment: The range set is collection of strings composed of 4 letters. In other words the universe is set of quaternary strings of length at most 15

Answer (score 0):

Count-Min Sketch requires 2-wise independent hash functions, but in practice, I strongly recommend [MurmurHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). It is fast and robust, works perfectly well for Count-Min Sketch.